# Django - generic ModelAdmin definition

Tags: python, django

This is a newbie question.

I have multiple models that I would like to show in admin view. I would like to show all model's fields when viewing a list of records for a model.
I'd like to define a generic ModelAdmin subclass which will be able to list out all fields for a model. But not sure how to pass the class objects to it. `admin.py` looks like this

```
class ModelFieldsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def __init__(self, classObj):
        self.classObj = classObj
        self.list_display = [field.name for field in classObj._meta.get_fields()]


admin.site.register(Candy, ModelFieldsAdmin)
admin.site.register(Bagel, ModelFieldsAdmin)
```

How can I pass the classObj (which would be one of the models Candy or Bagel)  , and also ensure that the `get_list_display()` picks up the value from `self.list_display` ?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the right approach. You shouldn't override `__init__` for an admin class.

Rather, define `get_list_display` and access `self.model`:

```
def get_list_display(request):
    return [field.name for field in self.model._meta.get_fields()]
```

Comment: Agreed. this worked. My followup question would be , is there a more efficient way to do it ? get_list_display method gets called multiple times, and so this parsing code would be called many times even though the result would always be the same. Can we do it somehow at init time so it's only done once per class instance ?

Comment: Well you could fairly easily memoize it, but I can't help feeling this would be an unnecessary optimisation. That simple list comprehension isn't adding any significant overhead to the request.